# Javascript: Function that returns Nicknames based on Regex

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that takes a string name as an argument and returns the first 3 or 4 letters as a nickname. If the 3rd letter is a consonant, return the first 3 letters.

```
nickname("Robert") //=> "Rob"
nickname("Kimberly") //=> "Kim"
```

If the 3rd letter is a vowel, return the first 4 letters.

```
nickname("Jeannie") //=> "Jean"
nickname("Douglas") //=> "Doug"
```

If the string is less than 4 characters

```
return "Error: Name too short".
```

My try

```
function nicknameGenerator(name) {
  return (name.length < 4 ? 'Error: Name too short.' :
    /^[a-z]{2}[aeiou]/.test(name)?
    name.slice(0,4) : name.slice(0,3)
  )
}
```

When invoked the function returns:

```
nickname("Robert") //=> "Rob"
nickname("Douglas") //=> "Dou"
nickname("Jim") //=> "Error: Name too short".
```

So it basically just does not work for when the third character is a vowel.

Comment: This kind of use of the ternary operator should be criminal... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to make your regex case-insensitive so it doesn't always return false due to the capital letter at the start of the string (note the `i` after the regex):

```js
function nicknameGenerator(name){

  return (name.length<4? 'Error: Name too short.' :

          /^[a-z]{2}[aeiou]/i.test(name)?

          name.slice(0,4) : name.slice(0,3)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Simpler and more readable approach

There's actually no need to use tricky regex. [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) may come in handy to find out whether the 3-rd character (`name[2]`) of your input string is a vowel (seen within `'aouie'` string):

```js
const names = ['Robert', 'Douglas', 'Kimberley', 'Jeannie', 'Jim']

      nickname = s => 
        s.length<4 ?
        'Error: Name is too short' :
        s.slice(0, 'aouie'.includes(s[2]) ? 4 : 3)

console.log(names.map(nickname))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test matches two lower case characters, but no uppercase chars.

use

```
/^[a-z]{2}[aeiou]/i.test
```

or

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{2}[aeiou]/.test
```